# How do I change the color settings in emacs23 running in a terminal emulator?

Tags: emacs, emacs23, xterm

I use xterm and set its appearance in `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
XTerm*background:       paleTurquoise
XTerm*foreground:       black
```

I also use emacs, but set its appearance differently in `~/.emacs`:

```
(set-background-color "black")
(set-foreground-color "yellow")
```

I usually run emacs within the terminal emulator with `emacs -nw`, rather than creating a separate X window.  For some reason, this doesn't work properly for emacs23; instead, emacs retains the pale turquoise background of my xterm window.  Looking at [what's new in emacs23](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/NEWS.23.2), I noted that:

> ** When running in a new enough xterm (newer than version 242), Emacs asks xterm what the background color is and it sets up faces accordingly for a dark background if needed (the current default is to consider the background light).

So it's a feature, not a bug?  Anyway, is there some way that I can I tell emacs23 to ignore the xterm background settings when running in console mode, and use the settings in `~/.emacs` instead?

I'll also note that:

- It works fine in emacs23 running in a separate X window (without the `-nw` option).
- It worked fine in emacs22; and I'm not really sure whether I need to use emacs23...
- Running `M-x set-background-color` within `emacs23 -nw` has no effect.
- It's not just xterm: the same problem exists with `$TERM=cygwin`, for example.

UPDATE: the best answer seems to be to use the `-fg` and `-bg` command-line options...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `TERM=xterm-256color` is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.  I think the problem is how to override a default behavior of emacs23 (that didn't exist in emacs22).  When I run `emacs23 -nw`, the display shows colors -- but they're the wrong ones.  It adopts the settings from my terminal and doesn't allow me to change them.

Comment: what about emacs -nw -fg <a color> -bg <another color> ? Does it work ?

Comment: Yes, the command-line arguments seem to do it, thanks!  It certainly isn't a pretty solution, but I guess I can set an alias in my `.bashrc` and then try to remember that I this particular configuration can't be set in my `.emacs`.

Comment: @Anonymous alias for -bg <color> is not necessary.  Instead (set-background-color "blue") use (set-face-attribute 'default nil :background "blue") which works works in terminal.